# Display a set of Images from a folder on Web2py

Tags: python, database, image, web2py

I am a web2py newbie and I have the following doubt.
I have a web2py application which take some inputs from the user and then generate some images. These images are then stored inside a folder under the private folder.
I want to display these images on the web2py application. 
How do I do that? Also, I don't want to upload the images as a database but simply read them from the folder and display it directly in the application. I got a reference from here:
http://www.widecodes.com/0xmqqVkXkP/web2py-downloading-files-displaying-images.html

But, couldn't quite understand it.
Any help?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know the file name and path, you can return any file to the browser via a controller action that calls `response.stream`. In a controller (e.g., default.py):

```
import os

def serve_file():
    filename = request.args(0)
    path = os.path.join(request.folder, 'private', 'file_subfolder', filename)
    return response.stream(path)
```

In a view, you would then include an image as follows:

```
<img src="{{=URL(default, serve_file, args=filename)}}" />
```

If the images are intended to be public, a better option is to store them in the /static folder -- any files in /static can simply be served directly via their URL:

```
<img src="{{=URL('static', 'image_files', args=filename)}}" />
```

This method does not require a special controller action to call `response.stream`.